# Is my security design sound?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, clojure

I have a specific need for security which means I'm writing more security-related code than I'm comfortable with. If what I'm doing is solved by a library somewhere, please, let me know and I'll drop my implementation immediately.

I have a server written in Java (actually Clojure) and a client written in JavaScript (actually ClojureScript) that runs as an Electron application. I need various clients applications to exchange information through the server ever being able to access that information: I need end to end encryption.

To implement end-to-end encryption I want to have a private public key-pair generated in the client and then the public key and an encrypted version of the private key will be uploaded to the server. Then, by doing a sort of challenge response in which the client signs a piece of random data and the server verifies it, the server would authenticate the user.

The registration process includes generating an Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman key pair, specifically, P-521 (secp521r1) which seems to be a good choice according to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/78621/which-elliptic-curve-should-i-use

After generating that, generate a 16 byte salt and then I pbkdf2 the password 872791 times with that salt, with a keylen of 32 and using sha512. Using the hashed key I encrypt the private key with aes-256-ctr. The last step is concatenating the salt length, the salt and the encrypted private key and send it to the server.

I'm assuming all of this happens over a TLS-secured channel, HTTPS, in which the validity of the certificate of the server is verified in the usual way, through the CAs. In the future I might use certificate pinning to increase security.

Is this a sound design? Does it look secure? Is there any or all of this that I could just delegate to a third party open source library that is well maintained?

My actual code:

```
(def elliptic-curve-name "secp521r1")                       ; https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/78621/which-elliptic-curve-should-i-use
(def encryption-algorithm "aes-256-ctr")                    ; http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/
(def hash-bytes 32)
(def salt-bytes 16)
(def pbkdf-digest "sha512")
(def iterations 872791)

(defn encrypt-text [text key]
  (let [salt (.randomBytes crypto salt-bytes)
        salt-string (.toString salt "base64")
        hashed-password (.pbkdf2Sync crypto key salt iterations hash-bytes pbkdf-digest)
        text-cipher (.createCipher crypto encryption-algorithm hashed-password)
        encrypted-text (gstring/format "%04d%s%s%s"
                                       (count salt-string)
                                       salt-string
                                       (.update text-cipher text "utf8" "hex")
                                       (.final text-cipher "hex"))]
    encrypted-text))

(defn decrypt-text [encrypted-text key]
  (let [salt-length (js/parseInt (subs encrypted-text 0 4) 10)
        salt (.from js/Buffer (subs encrypted-text 4 (+ salt-length 4)) "base64")
        hashed-key (.pbkdf2Sync crypto key salt iterations hash-bytes pbkdf-digest)
        encrypted-text (subs encrypted-text (+ salt-length 4))
        text-decipher (.createDecipher crypto encryption-algorithm hashed-key)]
    (str (.update text-decipher encrypted-text "hex" "utf8")
         (.final text-decipher "utf8"))))

(defn generate-key-pair [password]
  (let [diff-hell (.createECDH crypto elliptic-curve-name)
        public-key (.generateKeys diff-hell "base64")
        private-key (.getPrivateKey diff-hell "base64")
        encrypted-private-key (encrypt-text private-key password)]
    [public-key private-key encrypted-private-key]))
```

Comment: I'm not trying to say this is off-topic, but if you find the answers you get here unsatisfactory, InformationSecurity might give you a better answer.

Comment: Why worry about doing this manual encryption? Why not just use TLS with strong ciphers and use client certs for authentication?

Comment: He is asking about the privacy of "data at rest" while it is stored in the server. TLS protects "data in transit"

Comment: @zaph: ah, yes, I can see that. I'm no longer working at Qredo, this is for a personal project. I need to update that. And when I said 30 minutes review with an expert, it wasn't me. At Qredo I had the pleasure of working with really good people that knew security and encryption. As the CTO I would help with tech decisions, but everything would be explained to me and generally I would ask naive, stupid and hard questions until people made their own decisions. Other than that, there was a lot of day to day management including working on fundraising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent start. These kind of questions are tricky and there is no way to prove these things secure. There are some good conceptual "pillars" to guide ones thoughs on it:

The pillars of security:

- Privacy: 
  This code does not provide it. An attacker in the middle can read the structure of the message and can understand almost all of it. This gives them a strong stance. This system is open to replay attacks.
- Authentication
  By matching the password hash you are giving a strong assurance that this person does indeed know the password. PBKDF2 with a salt is state of the art and looks like you have this down.
- Integrity:
  This code does not provide it. the public key could be changed in flight. An attacker can substitute their own public key and cause the system to generate messages that they then could read. This attack is dependent on the rest of the system to detect the breach and respond to it, by comparing the public and private keys. This could open the system to known or unknown crypto attacks by allowing a "chosen key attack" which is generally considered dangerous. You really need to assure the integrity of the entire message. An attacker can take a password and key they do know along with a private key they do know, and switch them. Combined with replay attacks this will likely break the system.

Suggestions:

- The structure of the entire message must be authenticated. There are two approaches to this. Either use a keyed MAC (Message Authentication Code) or use an "Authenticated Encryption" algorithm. MACs are included in more of the common crypto libraries. Don't roll your own MAC, and don't try to use a hash for this.
- The privacy of the message should be ensured. This can be accomplished by ensuring that The message is send over TLS (you may already be doing this).
- the message must include protection against replay attacks. This can be done in many ways. One strong way is to use a NONCE (Number used ONCe) so the server will only ever accept each message once. This must not be "per user" because many replay attacks are cross user.

The part you are absolutly doing correctly is asking for public scrutiny early in the process. This puts you *way* ahead of the industry norm.  remember that

> "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break."

https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html

EDIT: make sure the password that protects them from you guessing their private key is not the same password you use to authenticate them (and that there is no way for them to use the same password)

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to say, I'm doing this on top of TLS and I'm counting on the CAs to avoid man-in-the-middle attack. One day I might do certificate pinning to increase security but I do know that comes with lots of small idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Potentially naive question. Can't I count on TLS to for auth and avoiding replay attacks?

Comment: You likely can use SSL to do this, As long as you do it on purpose and spell it out when doing the security analysis. Try to think of this from the perspective that each of the parties involved could be the attacker, 1. the person, 2. their browser, 3. MITM, 4. Your server, 5. your DB. and then try not to go crazy from professional paranoia.

Comment: You must do certificate pinning to avoid MITM attacks.

Comment: @zaph I don't think that's true. Using CAs mitigates MITM attacks. Certificate pinning mitigates them a lot more. For the initial phase of this product, CAs is *mitigation enough*.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I authenticate them by having the private key. The whole goal is not to use the password anymore for auth, so, I never see that password.